# Change url without reloading the page

Tags: javascript

How can I pass from this type of url:

```
http://domain.com
```

To this type:

```
http://domain.com/#0123456789
```

Without reloading the page.

I do not want to use the HTML5 `window.history.replaceState` function, as it does not work with the older versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: the hash link is easy and would work in all browsers. The url replacement is not possible in old browsers. http://caniuse.com/#search=history I would just fallback on hash links in IE9...

Comment: `http://domain.com/#0123456789` just make this a hyperlink - the page should not be reloaded as it is just a anchor link within the page.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer:

```
location.hash = "0123456789";
```

Sorry to answer my own question...but no answer gave the right point.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
window.location += "/#/123456";
console.log(location.hash);
```